# sessionStorage changes aren't firing 'storage' event

Tags: javascript, html

I was following [this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) to see if I could enable updates on all open webpages of my site if someone has multiple tabs open.

Basically, I set the listener and check to see if the `cart` key was changed

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
  if (e.key === "cart") {
    console.log(`cart changed: ${e.newValue}`);
  }
});
```

When I change `localStorage.cart` from another tab on the same website, the event fires just fine in the first tab:

```
setInterval(function(){
    localStorage.cart = "localStorage 1";
    setTimeout(function(){
        localStorage.cart = "localStorage 2";
    },2000);
},4000);
```

But when I use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage` it doesn't:

```
setInterval(function(){
    sessionStorage.cart = "sessionStorage 1";
    setTimeout(function(){
        sessionStorage.cart = "sessionStorage 2";
    },2000);
},4000);
```

Does the `storage` event only fire for `localStorage` and not `sessionStorage`?

Tested on chrome only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sessionStorage is isolated for each tab, so they can't communicate. Events for sessionStorage are triggered only in between frames on the same tab.

These codepens provide a good example

[Storage Writer](https://codepen.io/surdu/pen/QGZGLO?editors=1010) writes to storage

```
function writeSession()

    {
      sessionStorage.setItem("test", Math.random());
    }

    function writeLocal()
    {
      localStorage.setItem("test", Math.random());
    }
```

[Storage Reader](https://codepen.io/surdu/pen/GNYNrW?editors=1010) listens for storage event (keep this open in a different tab.)

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  

  if(e.storageArea===sessionStorage) {
    $("#output").append('Session storage change <br>');   
  }

  if(e.storageArea===localStorage) {
    $("#output").append('Local storage change <br>');   
  }

});
```

You will notice that when you press the "Write local" button, in both the iframe and the opened tab the event is captured, but when you press the "Session write" only the embedded iframe captures the event.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my post. I know that the event is fired in windows *other than* the one where the storage was changed. That's not under question here. What's confusing is that the event only fires for localStorage changes, not sessionStorage changes