# Update data on different page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have these 2 pages

Page 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="save();"/>
<div id ="stat"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var x=1 ;
    var test = document.getElementById("stat");
    function save() {
        x+=1;
        test.innerHTML=x;
        localStorage.setItem("value",x);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="stat"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var stat = document.getElementById("stat");
document.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
        stat.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("value");
    }, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is that

1. Open `Page 1` and `Page 2` on two different tabs (or window) in browser.
2. Go to `Page 1`
3. click the button.
4. Value in `Page 1` gets updated. Also the value in `Page 2` gets updated simultaneously.
5. Click the button how many times you want and gets the same behaviour.

I searched a little bit and got the idea to use local storage but this does not work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean that having two windows opened and to communicate between them?

Comment: Should work on same origin - I am not so convinced about `addEventListener('storage'`

Comment: Windows or tab, anything is helpful.

Comment: Also make it a type=button

Comment: R u writing ur javascript within script in each page like this or loading it from external js file.Because the `id` of div also matters.And also why `document.addEventListener('storage',`

Comment: yes the js are within the script and the event listener is there because I want to update the value on 2nd page automatically.

Comment: I would replace the 'storage' event listener with a timeout or interval of maybe two seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sessionStorage changes aren't firing 'storage' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734395/sessionstorage-changes-arent-firing-storage-event)

Comment: @Eular If you answer your own question and mark it as the accepted, it will help other people in the future when they have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1):

As it says here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp :

***Web storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.***

So, two offline webpages can't share the same local storage. They have to be opened from the same domain. One way to do this is to open them from a localhost web server. Then it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about this js in the browser environment (unlike others like nodejs), Unfortunately, I think what you are trying to do isn't possible simply because this is not the way it is supposed to work.

Html pages are delivered to the browser via HTTP Protocol, which is a 'stateless' protocol. If you still needed to pass values in between pages, there could be 3 approaches:

1. Session Cookies
2. HTML5 LocalStorage
3. POST the variable in the url and retrieve them in next.html via window object

Comment: I believe it can be done if the 2nd window / tab is opened by the first one so they can reference each other. A lot of things only work within the same origin I believe though.

Comment: can you provide a small example with any of the three?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe your page will be notified when the other page sets the data. I am happy to be proven wrong. In the meantime try this:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() { 
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("value") || "nothing yet";
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: In first.html

```
function testJS() {
    var b = document.getElementById('name').value,
        url = 'http://path_to_your_html_files/next.html?name=' + encodeURIComponent(b);

    document.location.href = url;
}
```

And in next.html:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.name;
}
```

Description: javascript can't share data between different pages, and we must to use some solutions, e.g. URL get params (in my code i used this way), cookies, localStorage, etc. Store the name parameter in URL (?name=...) and in next.html parse URL and get all params from prev page.

Comment: This just opened the 2nd page in place of the 1st page

Comment: You may be confused about what I want to do. check my question again